# Request Linux Capabilities During Runtime

Tags: c, linux, linux-capabilities

I am developing a program in C that requires temporary use of some capabilities that require elevation to acquire and would rather not just have users issue sudo because it will be one time setup.

How would I go about granting capabilities such as CAP_CHOWN to enable changing file ownership or similar actions guarded by a capability?

### A note on possible duplicates

When I asked this before it got closed as a duplicate. The question that was cited as the original question isn't the same question I had posted. I want a very specific set of capabilities, not root access.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/capset.2.html

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cap_get_proc.3.html

Comment: in Linux to change ownership of a file you must be a privileged user so you must be root.

Comment: Please do not add meta-commentary or meta-complaints to your questions. The point of this site is to provide useful resources for future readers - so please keep all material focussed exclusively on the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common method to do provide extra capabilities to a process is to assign filesystem capabilities to its binary.

For example, if you want the processes executing `/sbin/yourprog` to have the  `CAP_CHOWN` capability, add that capability to the permitted and effective sets of that file: `sudo setcap cap_chown=ep /sbin/yourprog`.

The [setcap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html) utility is provided by the libcap2-bin package, and is installed by default on most Linux distributions.

It is also possible to provide the capabilities to the original process, and have that process manipulate its effective capability set as needed.  For example, Wireshark's `dumpcap` is typically installed with CAP_NET_ADMIN and CAP_NET_RAW filesystem capabilities in the effective, permitted, and inheritable sets.

I dislike the idea of adding any filesystem capabilities to the inheritable set.  When the capabilities are not in the inheritable set, executing another binary causes the kernel to drop those capabilities (assuming KEEPCAPS is zero; see [prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) and [man 7 capabilities](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) for details).

As an example, if you granted `/sbin/yourprog` only the CAP_CHOWN capability and only in the permitted set (`sudo setcap cap_chown=p /sbin/yourprog`), then the CAP_CHOWN capability will not be automatically effective, and it will be dropped if the process executes some other binary.  To use the CAP_CHOWN capability, a thread can add the capability to its effective set for the duration of the operations needed, then remove it from the effective set (but keep it in the permitted set), via [prctl()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) calls.  Note that the libcap `cap_get_proc()`/`cap_set_proc()` interface applies the changes to *all* threads in the process, which may not be what you want.

For *temporarily* granting a capability, a worker sub-process can be used.  This makes sense for a complex process, as it allows delegating/separating the privileged operations to a separate binary.  A child process is forked, connected to the parent via an Unix domain stream or datagram socket created via socketpair(), and executes the helper binary that grants *it* the necessary capabilities.  It then uses the Unix domain stream socket to verify the identity (process ID, user ID, group ID, and via the process ID, the executable the other end of the socket is executing).  The reason a pipe is not used, is that an Unix domain stream socket or datagram socketpair socket is needed to use the `SO_PEERCRED` socket option to query the kernel the identity of the other end of the socket.

There are known attack patterns that need to be anticipated and thwarted.  The most common attack pattern is causing the parent process to immediately execute a compromised binary after forking and executing the privileged child process, timed just right so the capabled child process trusts the other end is its proper parent executing the proper binary, but in fact control has been transferred to a completely different, compromised or untrustworthy binary.

The details on exactly how to do this securely are a software engineering question much more than a programming question, but using `socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0, fdpair)` and verifying the socket peer is the parent process still executing the expected binary more than just once at the beginning, are the key steps needed.

---

The simplest example I can think of is using prctl() and CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE filesystem capability only in the permitted set, so that an otherwise unprivileged process can use a privileged port (1-1024, preferably a system-wide subset defined/listed in a root or admin-owned configuration file somewhere under /etc) to provide a network service.  If the service will close and reopen its listening socket when told to do so (perhaps via SIGUSR1 signal), the listening socket cannot simply be created once at the beginning then dropped.  It is a pretty good match for the *"keep in permitted set, but only add to effective set of the thread that actually needs it, then drop it immediately afterwards"* pattern.

For CAP_CHOWN, an example program might acquire it into its effective and permitted sets via the filesystem capability, but use a trusted configuration file (root/admin modifiable only) to list the ownership changes it is allowed to do based on the real user and group identity running the process.  Consider a dedicated "sudo"-style "chown" utility, intended for say organizations to allow team leads to shift file ownership between their team members, but one that does not use sudo.)

Comment: This is a very nice and well written answer, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not realistically possible to gain capabilities during runtime. The capabilities need to be already set **before** your software is started.

Some API functions like `capset` and `cap_set_proc` exist, but don't expect magic because the situation in which you could gain more capabilities will be both *rare* and a *security oversight*.

There are a few general ways of giving your software the required capabilities.

1. Set a specific capability on your binary with the `setcap` tool.
2. Use `sudo` to call your program. You already mentioned this yourself.
3. Set the `setuid` bit on your binary and set ownership to `root`. In this particular case that will be largely equivalent to calling your program with `sudo`.
4. Create a utility program that you apply one of the other methods on. Typically you would find such utility in a place like `/usr/libexec`. You then call the utility as a subprocess. I would consider this unnecessarily complex for simple situations. However, depending on the situations, this may be preferred over having a potential security risk of your software constantly running with too many privileges.

The first method should be considered the desired way. Your software should drop the capability as soon as it no longer requires it.

The CAP_CHOWN could be used for example to change ownership of `/etc/shadow`. The new owner could then change password for other users such as `root`, so effectively it could be equivalent to granting all capabilities. Hence, this capability is -like many others- potentially dangerous.